# Creating a boolean field in CloudKit Dashboard

Tags: ios, boolean, cloudkit

I want to create a field in one of our record types called 'match', and it to be boolean, either true or false. But in the new CloudKit dashboard there is no option to add such a field, see image below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to add a boolean field in the new CloudKit dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no BOOL type available, you'll have to use Int(64).

**updated based on comment question**

A BOOL is really just an int that can only be set to 0 or 1. So, create the INT value in cloudkit and:

```
BOOL myBool = FALSE; //or false, or 0
record[MY_INT64_FIELD] = myBool;
```

and when you read it back

```
NSNumber myBoolFromCloudKit = record[MY_INT64_FIELD];
BOOL myBool = myBoolFromCloudKit.integerValue
if (myBool)
{
     //do whatever
}
```

Comment: How do i set this up to act like a BOOL type?